# Is nodejs sussceptible to time drift?

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js

I'm troubleshooting an OAuth Authentication issue (invalid_grant) where one of two possible causes is the server's clock being out of sync with NTP. I've ensured the server's clock is synchronized.

Does nodejs instantiate its own clock or reference the system clock?

I expect it would reference the system clock. I only ask because restarting nodejs temporarily fixes the issue (invalid_grant), and I would like to rule out time synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

There are two way nodejs handle time.
using javascript `Date` or using `process.hrtime`

Assuming node core uses `process.hrtime` and you absolutely need to know, I would take a look at the libuv [uv_hrtime](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/v0.11.25/src/unix/core.c) function which node uses.

Maybe you have found a bug on the `uv_hrtime`. Whenever I use `process.hrtime` I never had problem like I did using `Date`

hope this points you at righ direction.